# Fnding wildcard string using Field Calculator script code?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to find part of a text string in the CLASS_NAME field and return a text string to the Abrv_Name field using the Field Calculator in ArcGIS 10 via a Python parser.

Here is what I have tried among other things with no success.

[image: field calculator image]

---

This worked within the field calculator.[image: field calculator]

Answer (score 12):

You want the ***in*** method detailed here: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#in

Swap

```
if Name=="*Emergent*":
```

with

```
if "Emergent" in Name:
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are specifically looking for wildcard behavior (probably not in this case) you can try the [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) module. Example:

```
from fnmatch import fnmatch

if fnmatch(Name, "*Emergent*"):
    return 'EM'
```